# Can anyone modify the following code to avoid the usage of "if"?

Tags: c++, c, logic

I am working on cuda currently and I got stuck on the code below. The code was originally written in matlab and I am trying to re-write it using cuda:

```
Pv = 0; Nv =0;
[LOOP]
v1 = l(li);
v2 = l(li+1);
if((v1>0) && (v2>0))
    Pv = Pv + 1;
elseif((v1<0) && (v2<0))
    Nv = Nv +1;
elseif((v1>0) && (v2<0))
    r = v1/(v1-v2);
    Pv = Pv + r;
    Nv = Nv + 1 - r;
elseif((v1<0) && (v2>0))
    r = v2/(v2-v1);
    Pv = Pv + r;
    Nv = Nv + 1 - r;
end
[LOOP END]
```

But, in cuda architecture, "if" expression is sometimes expensive, and I believe there is some way to avoid the usage of it, although I cannot figure it out now.

The main purpose of the code is to calculate the ratio of positive interval of negative interval and add them up respectively. In most of the situation , v1 and v2 have the same sign, but once they have different sign, I have to use a bunch of "if" or even perhaps "abs()" to handle the situation.

So, can anyone help me to re-write the code using C while using as few "if " as possible?

Comment: What are types of `Pv, Nv, v1, v2`? `float`, `double`? The CUDA compiler may use if-conversion to predicate the code, or convert these assignments into ternary operators, so trying to manually convert this into branchless code may be a premature optimization. It would be useful to check the generated SASS with `cuobjdump --dump-sass` and to profile the kernel to see whether branch divergence is much of an issue.

Comment: @njuffa They are all float variables. I'v never thought about checking binary code , I'll try it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you stated that the case of non-zero operands of like sign is the most common case, it would be best to handle the rare cases 3 and 4 using a branch, especially since they require an expensive division operation which we would not want to execute in the common (fast) path. Considering that `min()` and `max()` as well as the ternary operator are directly supported by hardware in GPUs, and that GPUs have extensive support for predication, I would suggest the slight re-write shown below. I have tested this using random combinations of two elements drawn from the set `{-0.0f, -3.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f}` to make sure cases with `v1==0` or `v2==0` are covered.

```
float Nv, Pv, v1, v2;
float r;
if ((v1 > 0) && (v2 > 0)) {
    Pv = Pv + 1;
} 
if ((v1 < 0) && (v2 < 0)) {
    Nv = Nv + 1;
}
if (((v1 > 0) && (v2 < 0)) || ((v1 < 0) && (v2 > 0))) { // rare case
    float s = min (v1, v2);
    float t = max (v1, v2);
    r = t / (t - s);
    Pv = Pv + r;
    Nv = Nv + 1 - r;
}
```

Compiled for sm_20, the code generated by the compiler is branchless, except for the rare slow path:

```
   /*0008*/         FSETP.LT.AND P2, PT, RZ, c[0x0][0x2c], PT;
   /*0010*/         FSETP.GT.AND P3, PT, RZ, c[0x0][0x28], PT;
   /*0018*/         FSETP.LT.AND P1, PT, RZ, c[0x0][0x28], PT;
   /*0020*/         MOV32I R4, 0x3f800000;
   /*0028*/         FSETP.GT.AND P4, PT, RZ, c[0x0][0x2c], PT;
   /*0030*/         PSETP.AND.AND P5, PT, P3, P2, PT;
   /*0038*/         PSETP.AND.AND P0, PT, P1, P2, PT;
   /*0040*/         FADD R0, R4, c[0x0][0x24];
   /*0048*/         PSETP.AND.AND P2, PT, P3, P4, PT;
   /*0050*/         FADD R4, R4, c[0x0][0x20];
   /*0058*/         PSETP.AND.OR P1, PT, P1, P4, P5;
   /*0060*/         MOV R2, c[0x0][0x30];
   /*0068*/         MOV R3, c[0x0][0x34];
   /*0070*/         SEL R0, R0, c[0x0][0x24], P0;
   /*0078*/         SEL R6, R4, c[0x0][0x20], P2;
   /*0080*/    @!P1 BRA 0xc8;
   /*0088*/         MOV R4, c[0x0][0x28];
   /*0090*/         FMNMX R5, R4, c[0x0][0x2c], PT;
   /*0098*/         FMNMX R4, R4, c[0x0][0x2c], !PT;
   /*00a0*/         FADD R5, R4, -R5;
   /*00a8*/         CAL 0xe0;                 // division
   /*00b0*/         FADD R5, R6, 1;
   /*00b8*/         FADD R0, R0, R4;
   /*00c0*/         FADD R6, R5, -R4;
   /*00c8*/         FADD R0, R0, R6;
```

Answer (score 4):

Utilising the fact that each of the expressions you use gives a 0 or 1 binary expression, I can get it down to one ternary operator:

```
// r is 0 if not case 3 or 4
r = (v1==v2)?0:((v1>v2)*v1-(v2>v1)*v2)/(v1-v2) * (v1*v2<0);
Pv += r + // cases 3 & 4
     (v1>0) && (v2>0); // case 1
Nv += r + // cases 3 & 4
     (v1<=0) || (v2<=0); // cases 2, 3 and 4
```

*(Edit: further optimisation untested!)*

However, this smells a lot like premature optimisation. Is it really the number of `if` statements that's going to cause the issue?

Comment: I'd agree this seems like premature optimisation. Whether this snippet is faster or not is going to be data dependent: it does a lot more work in the converged case.

Comment: @Jez: Indeed. I've made it slightly less bad by only calculating one value of `r`.

Comment: Did you also try to optimise source space? ;-)

Comment: And still spaces left to remove ... ;-)

Comment: As I did not dare to scribble around in your answer please have look at mine.

Comment: A ternary operator still generates conditional branch instruction; as far as CUDA goes, it's the same as an `if` statement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews indeed - that's why I called it out. I was trying to avoid the division by zero. See comments on alk's answer.

Comment: Yeah, this is indeed a premature optimisation, njuffa tested the code and it  turned out that cuda compiler would handle most of the case into branch less.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to *[ablish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3177124/abligh)*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31101278/694576):

This

```
r = (v1 == v2) ?0 :((v1 > v2) * v1 - (v2 > v1) * v2) / (v1 - v2) * (v1 * v2 < 0);
```

can be replaced by this

```
double ra[2] = {((v1 > v2) * v1 - (v2 > v1) * v2) / (v1 - v2) * (v1 * v2 < 0), 0.};
r = ra[!!(v1 == v2)];
```

removing the last ternary operator.

---

Update:

The `!!` is useless so the 2nd line above should just be:

```
r = ra[v1 == v2];
```

---

As pointed out by *abligh* in a [comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101154/can-anyone-modify-the-following-code-to-avoid-the-usage-of-if/31101450?noredirect=1#comment50218465_31101450) we might get a division by zero during initialisation of `ra`, so we only want to do the appropriate calculation:

```
double r0(double v1, double v2)
{
  return 0;
}

double r1(double v1, double v2)
{
  return ((v1 > v2) * v1 - (v2 > v1) * v2) / (v1 - v2) * (v1 * v2 < 0);
}

double (*rf[2])(double v1, double v2) = {r0, r1}; 

...

r = rf[fabs(v1 - v2) < EPSILON](v1, v2); /* With EPSILON like 0.00001 or what ever accuracy is needed. */
```

Comment: Shouldn't `double ra[1]` be `double ra[2]`? What is the point of the `!!` in `ra[!!(v1 == v2)]`?

Comment: @Jez: Aargh, yesyes, sure. Fixed. Thanks. :-}

Comment: CUDA doesn't like dynamic indexing of thread-local arrays either sadly, so I'd expect `ra` to be placed in the stack frame rather than registers. This would almost certainly hurt performance much more than the branching.

Comment: @Jez: The `!!` is just sugar. It makes sure `(v1 == v2)` evaluates to a "true" boolean. Not really necessary when doing hardcode C. But looking a second time you are right it's redundant. Copypasta garbage.

Comment: @Jez: Ok, might be. I'm not the CUDA guy. My intend was just trying to eleminate if-clauses/ternary operations ...

Comment: @alk the problem is that if `v1==v2` you may be dividing by zero (albeit multiply by zero again after)

Comment: How about dividing by `((v1 - v2)*(v1*v2<0) + (v1*v2>=0))`? That should make the division safe and the output doesn't much matter if you aren't going to divide by it (as it's only used when the signs of `v1` and `v2` differ). And avoids comparing floating point values for equality.

Comment: @abligh: Ohyes, probably also the most efficient approach.